# Unity 2018.2.2f is stuck on importing scripts when opening projects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a past project made in unity 2018.2.2f. Now, whenever I try to open my project it gets stuck on importing scripts and can't open it. Any ideas?

I tried to reboot unity and my pc, but it's not working.

It's just stuck on importing scripts

Comment: Try to check logs, C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Unity\Editor\upm.log

Comment: This is what I found, is something wrong with this?{"level":"info","message":"Starting Server","timestamp":"2019-07-18T06:00:54.506Z"}
{"level":"info","message":"Health Request received","timestamp":"2019-07-18T06:00:56.050Z"}

Comment: it's not exactly we are looking for, are you able to load another projects ? do you use git ?

Comment: Yeah, I was able to open other projects, just not this one. Before it froze I was importing cross-platform plugin and while it was importing it froze on importing scripts. So, I closed the project and try to open the project again, then it froze the entire thing. So I went to the project file and deleted the plugin, but still, nothing is working. No, I did not use git.

Comment: If you already deleted the plugin, you can try to delete the library folder

Comment: did you try removing all VS (or mono) project files and the Library folder? They get re-created when you open the unity project, so the current ones are corrupted, this might solve your issue.

Comment: make a back up copy of your project. Remove all folders and files except Assets Folder and ProjectSettings (Optional) and then open it in your Unity